# Using script to add new row below current row when cell in A is changed causes a row lower down to be deleted

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, insert

Here is the sheet I am working in:
[Before Script Runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJFVn.png)

This is a bid sheet I am making. I repeated categories just to show what happens the farther down an entry is made. When I enter an item in the dropdown lists in column A I need it to add a new line that directly below it, but above the next category, where another item can be entered.

The script that I have entered for it is:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  if (ss.getName() === "Entry") {
  var refRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var newRow = refRow + 1;
  var refCol = ss.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
  var RefRow = ss.getRange(refRow,1,refRow,refCol);

  RefRow.copyTo(ss.getRange(newRow, 1));
  ss.getRange("A"+newRow).clear();
}}
```

This script does add the line directly below, but it also deletes a line farther below.

[image]

The distance the deleted line is below the added line increases the farther down the sheet a change is made.

[image]

My question is how to make this work where the only thing that happens is that a row is added just below the row where a value is entered in column A and nothing is deleted or changed farther down in the sheet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Making use of the event object could save your script a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to getRange specifies the number of rows in the range. Since refRow is the row number of the cell, the behavior may be unintended.

For example, how about modifying it like this...

from:

```
var RefRow = ss.getRange(refRow,1,refRow,refCol);
```

to:

```
var RefRow = ss.getRange(refRow, 1, 1, refCol);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Added reason why it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I believe that this is getting closer to being the solution. I changed the code as you suggested and now it looks like it is pasting the formulas on the line directly below. So, instead of adding a line and deleting a line further down in the sheet, it may be deleting the line directly below and then inserting the new line there. I'm not sure.